# How to indent multiple lines on Vim?

Tags: vim, tabs, mapping, indentation

I want to be able to highlight lines I want to indent/reverse-indent and indent with tab and shift-tab respectively.

```
" for command mode reverse tab
nmap <S-Tab> <<
" for insert mode reverse tab
imap <S-Tab> <Esc><<i
" for command mode multiple line reverse tab(doesn't work)
nmap <Tab> i<
" for insert mode multiple line reverse tab(doesn't work)
imap <Tab> <

" for command mode tab
nmap <Tab> >>
" for command mode multiple line tab(doesn't work)
nmap <Tab> i>
" for insert mode multiple line tab(doesn't work)
imap <Tab> >
```

This is the last thing I need before I'm willing to use vim as my primary editor.

Comment: So? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

##### Quick start

In [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual),

- [<kbd><</kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3C) will shift selected lines leftwards and
- [<kbd>></kbd>](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3E) rightwards.

##### How to mark text in visual mode

To select and highlight your text, you need to [start using visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-start), (I usually do this by hitting <kbd>v</kbd>, or if coming from insert mode: <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) and select your text using the standard [motions](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html) (such as <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>) .

##### If you like, map other keys (not recommended)

If you do not want to use the default shortcuts <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd>, create mappings for use in [visual mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#Visual). You need [`:vmap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:vmap):

```
:vmap <Tab> >
:vmap <S-Tab> <
```

which would mean pressing

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> for "increase indent" and
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for "decrease indent"

But why do you need to create a mapping for this?

Sometimes it's better just to learn the Vim (or even Vi) keys (and <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> are easy anyway), and then you can use any installation, not just the one with your `.vimrc`.

For instance, you've put:

```
imap <Tab> <
```

This is a bad idea. This will make it harder for you to insert a tab-character into your text (even <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> won't work as I'd expect), and every time you type <kbd>tab</kbd> you'll insert a `<`.

Happy editing!

Comment: If I use my mouse to highlight, I use my right hand. < and > are both on the right side of the keyboard. Also it's out of habit since every editor I've used did this.

Comment: Your recommendation is quite good. I'll ditch the old highlight with mouse and tab paradigm. Do you still use the tab key for single line indenting or have you switched off to > for that too?

Comment: @user894091: Happy to help. I use the standard keybindings for the vast majority of editing actions.

Comment: Using < and > in visual mode works except that I can only hit it once, and then the selection context disappears and I have to re-select the text. Is there any way around this? So that I can nudge the block multiple times?

Comment: @Tapefreak: Type the number before you hit `>`. E.g. `3>` to indent three `'shiftwidth'`s

Comment: @Tapefreak: Or hit '.' to repeat the indentation, See [`:he single-repeat`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#single-repeat).

Answer (score 5):

In insert mode you can use <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> to remove/add an indent (respectively).

So, replace

```
imap <Tab> <
```

with

```
imap <Tab> <c-d>
```

and

```
imap <Tab> >
```

with

```
imap <Tab> <c-t>
```

In visual mode you can highlight a block and then hit <kbd><</kbd> or <kbd>></kbd>, but if you'd like it to be <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>, you can set it with `vmap` like you have done for the others.

Comment: That's still a bad idea. How do you insert a tab character?

Comment: @Johnsyweb ① I want to insert a tab character at least two orders of magnitude less frequently that I want to use it as a command. ② When you do what it (or any other character you've bound to something) you can use `<ctrl>+v<tab>` to insert a literal tab (or whatever else).

Answer (score 1):

put this in your .vimrc it's what you want

```
:map <Tab> >
:imap <Tab> <Esc> >
:vmap <Tab> >gv
:map <S-Tab> <
:imap <S-Tab> <Esc> <
:vmap <S-Tab> <gv
```

the gv after the vmaps will keep your highlights. the map and imaps will allow you insert in other modes. It's not quite like textmate, but it's getting there :)